# I would like to add translation to simple website

Tags: javascript, translation

I have to create a simple website (HTML, CSS and JS) and I want to have 3 different languages available. With Angular, I would use `ngx-translate`, so my question is if there is a way to do something similar here, without an npm package. I would like to have 3 .json files with the content of the translations and dynamically switch the language, but I am not sure if that is possible.
Another way to do it is to create 3 different HTML pages with static content and switch between them, but I would like the transition to be smooth, without reloading the page. Please advise if this is possible. Thanks!

Comment: Translation is best done on the server-side. The GET request can have a query param (i.e: `?lng=de`) that instructs the server to prepopulate specific placeholders with the specific translation. i18n. Than the server responds immediately with the static translated page. Otherwise doing it dynamically you risk to: send to the client entire translation libraries, flickering of content, re-layouting, repaint... Some crawlers might have problems in properly reading and indexing such dynamic content.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan - Thanks for the response.